# writing multiple lines of text into one file using R

Tags: r

I'm using write() to write multiple lines to the same file this way:

```
filename='out.txt'

write(c("\n\n","No of blues =", nrow(data1)), file=filename,append=FALSE)
write(c("\n\n","No of greens =", nrow(data2)), file=filename,append=Append)
write(c("\n\n","No of reds =", nrow(data3)), file=filename,append=Append)
```

data1, data2 and data3 are variable names.

But I got the following errors:

```
Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
 argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

Is there a solution in R for this problem?

Comment: You are trying to use write with a list, but write needs a vector. Try to check if that may the case.

Comment: I'm guessing that of the three lines in your example NONE of them are the line that produces that error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At a guess, you are trying to `write` a data frame. This is a guess, because the lines you give us should work. I don't believe they are giving the error. An important part of asking questions on here is doing a bit of work yourself to find out where the error is, and supplying self-contained code that generates the error. Like this doesn't:

```
Append=TRUE
filename='out.txt'
data1=data.frame(x=1:10)
data2=data.frame(y=1:3)
data3=data.frame(z=99)
write(c("\n\n","No of blues =", nrow(data1)), file=filename,append=FALSE)
write(c("\n\n","No of greens =", nrow(data2)), file=filename,append=Append)
write(c("\n\n","No of reds =", nrow(data3)), file=filename,append=Append)
```

If I run that (and if **YOU** run that too) then I don't get an error. But try this:

```
write(c("\n\n","data 1 is ", data1), file=filename,append=Append)
```

and looky look:

```
Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

Exactly your error. Maybe that's what you are doing. We don't know, because we haven't got any code from you that creates that error.

If you want to write a data frame to a file, use `write.table`.

Answer (score 1):

just use cat directly instead of write

```
filename='out.txt'

data1 = matrix(1:10, ncol=2)
data2 = matrix(1:20, ncol=2)
data3 = matrix(1:30, ncol=2)

cat("No of blues =", nrow(data1), "\n", file=filename, append=FALSE, sep='')
cat("No of blues =", nrow(data2), "\n", file=filename, append=TRUE, sep='')
cat("No of blues =", nrow(data3), "\n", file=filename, append=TRUE, sep='')

#results
cat(readLines(filename), sep="\n")

## No of blues =5
## No of blues =10
## No of blues =15
```

You can also combine the three lines into one call to cat so there is no need to mess with appending to files, which is always a risky proposition.

```
cat("No of blues =", nrow(data1), "\n",
    "No of blues =", nrow(data2), "\n",
    "No of blues =", nrow(data3), "\n", file=filename, sep='')

#results
cat(readLines(filename), sep="\n")

## No of blues =5
## No of blues =10
## No of blues =15
```

Comment: Thank you very both of you Spacedman and Jim; both solutions were terrific! problem solved